# Pandas to_datetime is not formatting the datetime value in the desired format (dd/mm/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I have the datetime values in the following format

```
    2017-09-11 01:18:38
    2017-09-11 01:34:30
    2017-09-11 05:03:57
    2017-09-11 09:55:48
    2017-09-11 09:59:10
    2017-09-11 12:09:05
```

I have to display the values in the format dd/mm/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM:

```
    11/09/2017  01:18:38 AM
    11/09/2017  01:34:30 AM
    11/09/2017  05:03:57 AM
    11/09/2017  09:55:48 AM
    11/09/2017  09:59:10 AM
    11/09/2017  12:09:05 PM
    11/09/2017  12:08:16 PM
```

I am using the following code to do that , however it doesnt change the format

```
data_f1['Reported Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_f1['Reported Date'], 
   format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given a **string column**, use [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert it to a datetime object column.

Given an ***already existing* datetime column**, use `dt.strftime` to convert it to a string column in a particular format.

This is how it works, and you can't change that.

```
df

                 date
0 2017-09-11 01:18:38
1 2017-09-11 01:34:30
2 2017-09-11 05:03:57
3 2017-09-11 09:55:48
4 2017-09-11 09:59:10
5 2017-09-11 12:09:05

df.date.dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

0    09/11/2017 01:18:38 AM
1    09/11/2017 01:34:30 AM
2    09/11/2017 05:03:57 AM
3    09/11/2017 09:55:48 AM
4    09/11/2017 09:59:10 AM
5    09/11/2017 12:09:05 PM
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Note that there is *no use* in changing the representation of a *`datetime`* column, because those are *`datetime` objects*, and have their own representation defined by the `__repr__` method of their class.

Comment: Is there no way i can change the format of the datetime  objects , because i need to pass this values to excel where it has to be in this format itself , however if i use strftime it will pass the value as string to the excel and not as time objects

Comment: @JitendraAswani When you write a date to excel, it is written as a string... think about that for a second. "Changing the repr of the date" is something you can do if you are a core pandas developer. Otherwise, ... what you want is `strftime`.

Comment: so what is format in to_datetime function used for ?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i'd rather use a ["standard way"](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_datetime.html#ex-pandas-datetime) ;-)

Comment: @MaxU You're right... that would be better... unfortunately did not know about this excel business when writing the answer (was not mentioned in the question).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i just realized that OP didn't say anything about excel in the question itself. So your answer perfectly answers the question - +1 :)

Comment: @MaxU Thank you kind sir :-)

Comment: @JitendraAswani Okay. You have not mentioned excel in the question and so my answer does not talk about excel. But if you insist on this, take a look at the link MaxU provided, and use `pd.ExcelWriter` and pass `datetime_format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"` when writing your dataframe. We usually frown upon chaining unrelated questions to your main one in the comments, but I'll help you out this once.

Comment: @MaxU           Your link helped me , cant upvote , sorry

Comment: @JitendraAswani, glad it helps :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sorry it took me sometime figuring out my other issues , your answer cleared many doubts for me .